# Combining 2 inner join query as one

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I am stuck trying to combine output from 3 tables into one single query.

Here are the table structure

### BL_PLAYERS

player_id   int(10)
league_id   int(10)
player_name     varchar(150)
gender  tinyint(3)
initial_hc  smallint(6)
total_score     int(10)
total_games     smallint(6)
current_hc  smallint(6)
league_player   tinyint(3)

### BL_POINTS

series_id   int(10)
player_id   int(10)
point   smallint(6)

### BL_LEAGUES_RANK

series_id   int(10)
player_id   int(10)
rank    smallint(6)
last_game   smallint(6)
true_score  smallint(6)
handicap    smallint(6)
total_score     smallint(6)

Here are my 2 inner join statements.. they look almost identical... but I cant find a way to combine it so that the first sql will return additional column which is the sum(rn.total_score) from BL_LEAGUES_RANK

```
SELECT pl.player_id, pl.player_name, pl.gender, pl.league_player, SUM( pt.point ) AS total_points FROM `bl_players` pl  INNER JOIN `bl_points` pt ON pl.player_id = pt.player_id AND series_id =1 GROUP BY player_id ORDER BY total_points DESC 

SELECT pl.player_id, pl.player_name, pl.gender, pl.league_player, SUM(rn.total_score) as total_pinfall FROM `bl_players` pl INNER JOIN `bl_leagues_rank` rn ON pl.player_id = rn.player_id AND series_id =1 GROUP BY player_id ORDER BY total_pinfall DESC
```

Is it even possible? Thank you in advance for any input on this...

Answer (score 0):

I think this ought to work....

```
SELECT pl.player_id, pl.player_name, pl.gender, 
    pl.league_player, SUM( pt.point ) AS total_points 
FROM bl_players pl, bl_points pt, bl_leagues_rank rn
WHERE pl.player_id = pt.player_id AND series_id =1 
    AND pl.player_id = rn.player_id
GROUP BY player_id ORDER BY total_points DESC
```

Comment: i have tried it, but the number being produced by mysql is way over what it should be... found a way by combining inner join and left join. So my final query would appear as this...

SELECT pl.player_id, pl.player_name, pl.gender, pl.league_player, sum( pt.point ) AS total_points, sum(rn.total_score) as total_pinfall FROM bl_players pl INNER JOIN bl_points pt ON pl.player_id = pt.player_id AND pt.series_id = 1 LEFT JOIN bl_leagues_rank rn ON pl.player_id = rn.player_id AND rn.series_id = 1 GROUP BY player_id ORDER BY total_points DESC

A bit complicated for me.. but it works..